# What is the proper way to send an Authorization 'token' using RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, authorization, restsharp

We built an API that is waiting for calls from some client software.  We have no problems GET (ting) and POST (ting) using Python but we have someone trying to access it using some  .Net Code based on the RESTSharp library and despite many hours of searching they cannot seem to get authorization.

Here is some Python code that works

```
POST_HEADER = {'Authorization': "Token a_valid_token_that_works_with_python code",
       'Content-Type':'application/json'} 
BASE_URL = 'https://api.ourendpoint.com/v1/user-tasks/'
#here is the code to POST some data - the authorization token is in POST_HEADER
response = requests.post(BASE_URL, data = JSON_STRING ,headers = POST_HEADER)
```

That works fine - but what **we think** is the analogous .Net code is not working - we get an authorization error - so something is wrong with the way the token is sent

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.ourendpoint.com/v1/");
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Token  a_valid_token_that_works_with_python code");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest("user-tasks", Method.POST);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

# there is some stuff here to create the data to be POST (ed) but we have
# taken that out so we could focus on just getting authorization

var obj = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

Our server responds with the following to the attempt to POST

```
    b'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Maybe even more interesting when we look at the server logs we see that the server is reading the POST attempt as a GET

```
January 29th 2018, 14:23:39.633API request with method: GET, URI: /v1/user-tasks/  b''  b'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}'    GET
```